# Book about a world whose citizens only communicated by hologram

Tags: story-identification

Some years ago (15?) I read a book about a world populated by individuals who only communicated by viewing holograms of each other. They could not stand to be physically together. Can anyone help me remember the author/book title? I'd love to reference it in class.

Comment: Are you sure it was specifically holograms, rather than something else like videoscreens? People use an audiovisual system, and mostly hate actual contact, in [The Machine Stops](http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/prajlich/forster.html) by E.M. Forster.

Comment: Do you remember any other details of the book? A plot detail, a character, even the cover? As it stands, this could cover several works I can think of.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224963/story-about-the-scientists-in-mars-that-are-less-cooperative-than-the-scientists (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 39):

Could this be Asimov's [The Naked Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Sun), which depicts the planet Solaria, a society of Spacers who abhor physical contact or proximity?

> The book focuses on the unusual traditions and culture of Solarian
>   society: the planet has a rigidly controlled population of twenty
>   thousand, and robots outnumber humans ten thousand to one, whereas
>   people are strictly taught from birth to despise personal contact, and
>   live on huge estates, either alone or with their spouse only.
>   **Communication is done via holographic telepresence (called viewing, as
>   opposed to in-person seeing).**

Comment: Solaria is also visited in Foundation and Earth.

Comment: Yes, but there is no communication via hologram then because all the inhabitants (save one) are dead.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, didn't mean for that to be an alternate answer, just a comment for anyone interested. Also, they're not all dead, we just only see one, but he's quite clear that there are others—about 1,200 I think.