# Story about the scientists in Mars that are less cooperative than the scientists of Earth

Tags: story-identification, isaac-asimov

I am trying to remember the name of a story detective story. In the story detective from earth sent to Mars in order to investigate something (murder?)and he need cooperation from the local scientists community. He figured out that the scientists in Mars that are less cooperative in their research than the scientists of Earth that tend to collaborate much more frequently. If i recall correctly it has something about the longer lifespan of the people in Mars.

I am pretty sure that this is an Asimov story.

Comment: This is a very brief description, can you remember anything else at all about it that you could [edit] in?

Comment: Are you sure it was Mars? The Asimov book about the Earth detective who visits the isolated society of a different planet is *The Naked Sun*, but that was Solaria, not Mars.

Comment: "Men are from Mars, Scientists are from Venus"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are sure this is an Asimov story then it sounds very like [The Naked Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Sun). This is a good match in everything except the location as it is set on the planet Solaris not Mars.

The detective, Elijah Baley, is sent to Solaris to investigate a murder. Compared to Earth, which has become very crowded, the Solarians live lives of luxury with thousands of robot attendants to take care of their every need. They also have lifetimes much longer than Terrans, though I don't think the details are discussed. The impact of the long lives is specifically referred as you describe by Baley when he is reporting back to his boss at the end of the investigation:

> “I believe I know the weaknesses of the Solarians, sir.”
>
> “You can answer my question? Good. Go ahead.”
>
> “Their weaknesses, sir, are their robots, their low population, their long lives.”
>
> Minnim stared at Baley without any change of expression. His hands worked in jerky finger-drawn designs along the papers on his desk. He said, “Why do you say that?”
>
> Baley had spent hours organizing his thoughts on the way back from Solaria; had confronted officialdom, in imagination, with balanced, well-reasoned arguments. Now he felt at a loss. He said, “I’m not sure I can put them clearly.”
>
> “No matter. Let me hear. This is first approximation only.”
>
> Baley said, “The Solarians have given up something mankind has had for a million years; something worth more than atomic power, cities, agriculture, tools, fire, everything; because it's something that made everything else possible.”
>
> “I don’t want to guess, Baley. What is it?”
>
> “The tribe, sir. Cooperation between individuals. Solaria has given it up entirely. It is a world of isolated individuals and the planet's only sociologist is delighted that this is so. That sociologist, by the way, never heard of sociomathematics, because he is inventing his own science. There is no one to teach him, no one to help him, no one to think of something he himself might miss.

Comment: Somehow I accidentally downvoted this.

Answer (score 10):

This has some similarities to the Isaac Asimov 1952 novel [David Starr, Space Ranger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Starr,_Space_Ranger) which was the first in a six book series published under the pseudonym Paul French.

Some items that match:

I am trying to remember the name of a story detective story. In the story detective from earth sent to Mars

> Match: as story is set on Mars

in order to investigate something (murder?)

> Match: Investigating deaths/murders due to what appears to be poisoned food supplies.

and he need cooperation from the local scientists community. He figured out that the scientists in Mars that are less cooperative in their research than the scientists of Earth that tend to collaborate much more frequently.

> Match: David works as part of the  Council of Science, which suppresses threats to the System's people and is a quasi governmental organization. On Earth he has full cooperation. On Mars he is met with resistance.

If i recall correctly it has something about the longer lifespan of the people in Mars.

> Non-match/partial Match?  The story suggests that intelligent native Martians living below the planet's surface are poisoning the food

it turns out

> The Martians do exist and are are disembodied intelligences. Energy-like beings (think Organians from Star Trek so effectively long-lived.

I am pretty sure that this is an Asimov story.

> Match. Though as Spencer correctly noted these were originally published under the pseudonym Paul French.

Comment: You should probably mention that [the Lucky Starr novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Starr_series) were published under a pseudonym, Paul French.

Comment: @Spencer.  Good point. Will do.